# symfony unable to find template

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

The main layout file is src/BD/TestBundle/views/layout.html.twig. 
I'm trying to extend it from a file located in src/BD/TestBundle/views/Default/index.html.twig. 
`{% 'BDTestBundle::layout.html.twig' }` throws a unable to find the template error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{% extends 'TestBundle:Default:layout.html.twig' %}`

`TestBundle` bundle name

`Dedault` directory name in `Resources`

`layout:html:twig` template name

Comment: Please notice that the file layout.html.twig is not in the directory named Default. It is one level up.